# meaning of "safe for"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> These behaviours are reflective of what is known as psychological
> safety – a group culture that the Harvard Business School professor
> Amy Edmondson defines as a “shared belief held by members of a team
> that the team is **safe for** interpersonal risk-taking.” Psychological
> safety is “a sense of confidence that the team will not embarrass,
> reject or punish someone for speaking up,” Edmondson wrote in a study
> published in 1999.

What does 'safe for' mean here? Is it same as 'safe from'?

Comment: Not really. If you're ***safe from harm***, that means you ***won't*** experience harm. But if a beach is ***safe for swimming***, that means you *can* safely swim there (quite possibly you ***will*** swim). Your "risk-taking" context is like my swimming - within the context of the team, it's safe to take risks. That's not at all the same thing as saying the team is safe ***from*** risk-taking. That would mean *No risk-taking can happen here. The team is a "risk-taking-free" zone*.

Answer (score 3):

> the team is safe for interpersonal risk-taking

This means that the team may take interpersonal risks safely.

"safe from" is different, example:

*Because the team is safe for interpersonal risk-taking, the members of the team will be safe from censure if they accidentally take things too far.*